# How to copy data in Redshift using DELIMITER option which has delimiter in the data itself?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have pipe delimited data which I am trying to copy from S3 to RedShift but COPY operation is failing with error code `1202 : Extra column(s) found` error.

When I looked into `stl_load_errors`, copy operation failed for rows which have | delimiter in them.

Sample data:

```
1|hello world|how|are you|
2|"hope|you|are|doing|good"|thank you|
3|I am fine|thank you|
```

For above mentioned data,     `2|"hope|you|are|doing|good"|thank you|` fails to get copied because it has | delimiter in itself even though it is inside double quotes.

My copy command looks like below:

```
COPY <DATABASE.TABLE NAME>
FROM 's3://path/to/file'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam:my_role'
delimiter '|'
dateformat 'auto'
IGNOREHEADER 1
MAXERROR 5;
```

AWS RedShift documentation has one example to load this type of data but they have used CSV option, not DELIMITER option.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

You should add the `REMOVEQUOTES` parameter.

From [Data Conversion Parameters - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-removequotes):

> Removes surrounding quotation marks from strings in the incoming data. All characters within the quotation marks, including delimiters, are retained.

Comment: Thanks John, I'll try this option let you know if it works.